# Текст на фоне логотипа

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть логотип в виде текста "Logo" и под ним ещё текст "logo text"
https://jsfiddle.net/4tp2hkL0/
Также под логотипом есть фон в виде картинки, и проблема в том, что "logo text" должен немного быть сверху нижней линии, и чтобы под текстом не было видно линии, но был виден фон.
Сделал чтобы линии скрывались с помощью overflow: hidden, но нижняя часть текста также скрывается.
Как это сделать правильно?
Может нужно по другому делать линии? Проблема именно в полосе вокруг текста Logo, и чтобы под текстом "logo text" не было видно этой полоски.

```css
aside{
  width: 50%;
}
header .logo h1{
    font-size: 32px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
aside{
    padding: 30px 33px;
    background-color: gray;
}
header .logo{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 3px solid rgba(197, 124, 24, 0.6);
  border-left: 3px solid rgba(197, 124, 24, 0.6);
  border-right: 3px solid rgba(197, 124, 24, 0.6);
  overflow: hidden;
}
header .logo h1{
  font-size: 48px;
  padding: 10px;
}
header .logo span{
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -9px;
  right: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 4px;
}
header .logo span::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(197, 124, 24, 0.6);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
header .logo span::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(197, 124, 24, 0.6);
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Logo</h1>
      <span>logo text</span>
    </div>
  </header>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
aside {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

header .logo h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

header .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, red, red 3px, transparent 3px, transparent 100%), linear-gradient(90deg, red, red 3px, transparent 3px, transparent 100%), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent calc(100% - 3px), red calc(100% - 3px), red 100%);
  background-size: 100% 100%, 100% calc(100% - 10px), 100% calc(100% - 10px);
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

header .logo h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
}

header .logo span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
}

header .logo span::before,
header .logo span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 10000%;
  height: 3px;
  background: red;
}

header .logo span::before {
  left: -5000%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

header .logo span::after {
  right: -5000%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Logo</h1>
      <span>logo text</span>
    </div>
  </header>
</aside>

<aside>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Logo Logo</h1>
      <span>logo</span>
    </div>
  </header>
</aside>

<aside>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Lo</h1>
      <span>logo</span>
    </div>
  </header>
</aside>

<aside>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Logo Logo Logo</h1>
      <span>l</span>
    </div>
  </header>
</aside>
```

Comment: немного не так как нужно. https://jsfiddle.net/5xhgrt41/  здесь видно, что линии внизу не на всю ширину

Comment: т.е. размер текста динамический

Comment: есть ещё варианты как это можно сделать правильно?